# Dynamic checkbox - save to database

Tags: mysql, sql, checkbox

I have certain problem. From the database I am picking photographs which they are creating up of certain kind gallery (and rather than that names of photographs) which later appropriately are being shown. By every photograph I have a checkbox type field. To every article it will be possible plus let us give 12 photographs to it. And here a question appears. In what way best to enrol the value of these photographs in the database? With placing he doesn't have value parameters of problem, because I am picking it up from the database and then but I am putting. An issue is puzzling me, whether to the table with articles (article) to put lines of type image1, image2, image3 itd, whether can take advantage of ENUM/SET type fields?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3XeG.png

If I select the 2 method, then I don`t know how send this in $_POST:

```
if($rowAllImage){
    foreach($rowAllImage as $GETimage){
        $news->setImage1($_POST[''.$GETimage['name'].'']);
        $news->setImage2($_POST[''.$GETimage['name'].'']); 
    }
}
<input type="checkbox" value="'.$GETimage['name'].'" name="'.$GETimage['name'].'" style="vertical-align: middle;"/></div>
```

How create a dynamic checkbox to save in database(MySQL)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a little changes in your checkbox tag. You can define a function and if it has to be checked, the function returns `checked="checked"`.

As I find from your question, `$GETimage['name']` doesn't return a Boolean value for checkbox status.

```
<input <?php $HasToBeChecked > 1 ? echo 'checked="checked"' : echo ""?> type="checkbox" value="'.$GETimage['name'].'" name="'.$GETimage['name'].'" style="vertical-align: middle;"/></div>
```

Comment: Are you can write a small example?

Comment: I've added the sample but you may have to change a little the sample for your usage.